# tcsh/vi-mode behavior difference between Solaris and Linux

Tags: linux, vim, solaris, tcsh, vi-mode

We have both Solaris and Linux environments at work.  We use tcsh as the standard shell for hundreds of users.  My question is about vi-mode in tcsh:

In Solaris, while I'm typing, I can backspace over previous chars, and then just start typing again.  Insert mode is intuitive, and the commandline seems to be in insert mode automatically -- I can backspace, and type, backspace and type, all as if I pressed ESC-i to enter insert mode explicitly (doing that BTW presents the same behavior as not doing it...)

In Linux however, using a slightly newer version of tcsh (6.17), as soon as I press backspace to backup over incorrect text, the editor exits insert mode, and thereafter, I have to press "i" to get back to inserting text.   Further, before backspace will erase the char to the left of the cursor, you have to press it twice -- it's switching mode apparently.   Then you have to press "i" to enter back to insert mode before you can start typing again, and so on and so on.   I find this Linux behavior really annoying and tedious.  What is possibly the reason for this difference in behavior?

BTW, my terminal in both cases is xterm.

thanks...

Comment: Answer: Either a bug or a difference in implementation between the two platforms assumming you are using IDENTICAL .cshrc/.tcshrc files.

Answer (score 0):

Type

`stty -a`

and look at the character after the word "erase". Sun has AT&T heritage and uses ^H (ASCII 8) to erase, while the tcsh has DEC/Berkeley heritage and uses ^? (ASCII 127).

You need to place a line like:

stty erase ^H

or

stty erase ^?

in your login file.